# How to Place OCO Order on Kucoin with Python?

Tags: python

I have tried to place the OCO-Order on Kucoin with Python(Kucoin-API)
But In API There is No OCO Order Placing Option.

## This is what i have tried?

```
OrderSL = KucoinCC.create_stop_order(symbol=coin,type='limit', side='sell', amount=AvailableAmount, price=StopLossTrigger,stopPrice=StopLoss,params=dict(stop='loss'))
                    OrderIDSL = OrderSL['id']

OrderTP = KucoinCC.create_stop_order(symbol=coin,type='limit', side='sell', amount=AvailableAmount, price=TakeProfitTrigger,stopPrice=TakeProfit,params=dict(stop='entry'))
                    OrderIDTP = OrderTP['id']
```

The Problem Is When i Placed this two orders.let's suppose when the price went on my TakeProfit stopPrice then Api is sending order to the OpenOrders from advance order and locking my full available Amount.
After That if Limit is Not Filled Completely and price Came Down than my another Stoploss order is canceled Because iam having No Amount as locked in my TakeProfit Order

Iam Expecting that my Orders should work as the OCO Order (One Cancels The Other.)

Answer (score 0):

```
OrderSL = KucoinCC.create_stop_order(symbol=coin,type='market', side='sell', amount=AvailableAmount, price=StopLossTrigger,stopPrice=StopLoss,params=dict(stop='loss'))
                    OrderIDSL = OrderSL['id']

OrderTP = KucoinCC.create_stop_order(symbol=coin,type='market', side='sell', amount=AvailableAmount, price=TakeProfitTrigger,stopPrice=TakeProfit,params=dict(stop='entry'))
                    OrderIDTP = OrderTP['id']
```

Currently Kucoin Doesn't Allow OCO Order For Making it Work You can use market Type

Comment: But I want to place limits because if I sold on Market my order will execute after 0.2 to 0.3 percent down